# Render XML Working But Render JSON Not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xml, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on a simple rails api and need to return the json, but unable to return it. Replacing json with xml worked for me and the code is returning the xml correctly but not the json.

```
module Api
  class AgendaController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

    def all
      render json:Person.all
    end
    def default_serializer_options
      {root:false}
    end
  end
end
```

Now if i replace  `render json:Person.all` with  `render xml:Person.all` it's working perfectly.

My Routes.rb file

```
 namespace :api, constraints: {format: :json} do
        get 'people' => 'agenda#all'

  end
```

Error:

NoMethodError in Api::AgendaController#all
undefined method `idm' for #

```
 def all
      render json: Person.all #ErrorHere
    end
```

Comment: what is the format of the request? if the request isn't in json, it's not going to return anything.

Comment: Just edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Hmm I just spun up a dummy app using your code as an example and it seems to work fine. What does your server console show when you make the request and have `render json: [...]` in the controller? Are you generating the request with your browser or `cURL` or what?

Comment: Tried both, the error remains the same.  Can you share your application?

Comment: sure: https://github.com/davidcpell/render_json